# utorrent won't download, I think it's the firewall

Tags: utorrent

I just changed my firewall to webroot. I tried to use utorrent, but the download speed stays at 0. I checked and webroot says that utorrent is allowed, but I can't find any other reason it wouldn't work. How can I fix this?

It worked before, I never had this problem until after I got webroot. Also, Webroot is the antivirus.

Comment: Please tell us more about your setup.  ISP, antivirus (not just firwewall) amount of seeders and amount of connections you make in utorrent.  Is it just one download, or all of them that have 0kbps?

Comment: Did it work before you installed Webroot?  Have you tried disabling or uninstalling Webroot to see if it works?

Answer (score 2):

Reasons why Bittorrent clients will not work at all (as opposed to working very slowly):

- No peers on torrent (torrent is stale)
- You're running a misbehaved client and all peers snubbed you (you'd be able to make connections, though)
- Firewall blocking any incoming connections and any outgoing connections except a few ports (likely 80/443).
- ISP doing the same.